# laravel dompdf - issue with font

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-4, pdf-generation, dompdf

I need extended support for latin based font, so I wanted to use default font "dejavu sans", but the text is completely white and it's ignoring css rules.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

I'm using laravel 4
Here's the code:

php

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView("project.accounting.pdf_offer", $data);
        $pdf->output();
        $dom_pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();
        $canvas = $dom_pdf->get_canvas();
        $canvas->page_text(35, 803, sprintf("%s {PAGE_NUM} %s {PAGE_COUNT}", Lang::get("default.page"), Lang::get("default.from")), null, 7, array(0, 0, 0));

        return $pdf->stream();
```

css

```
html, body {
outline: 0;
font-weight: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
line-height: 1;
color: #111;
background: white;
font-family: "dejavu sans", serif;
```

}

Comment: Show us some code, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @Anders no need to go negative right away, I was politely asking if someone had experience with it..
BTW I posted my code which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Nothing negative meant. I just concluded that it would be hard to help you without seeing the code no mather how much I would like to.

Comment: Is the font installed locally on your computer, or are you getting it using Google font or something like that?

Comment: Yes "dejavu sans" is coming with dompdf library.
Same problem occurs with the google fonts.
But when I use default fonts (serif, Couries, Helvetica) it's working fine except some special letters are missing.

Comment: Can you use the font in other context, for instance in a normal HTML file? Or PDF generated some other way? Do we know that this has something to do with dompdf?

Comment: How is the font being included in the view? I suspect this is because dompfd isn't able to access the font file/download it.

Comment: Is the CSS inline with the HTML document or in an external file? Even so, the text shouldn't be completely white. Is it white or just not represented visually (e.g. you can't see the characters, but you can copy/paste from the PDF)?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution to the problem - at first I was generating page number from controller, but then I moved it to template (inline) as script/php, and now it's fine.

Thanks for helping me.